# How to use pip-tools to install from a github repo?

Tags: pip, pip-tools

Here is a line in a req.in file (for [pip-compile](https://pypi.org/project/pip-tools/)) to get a package from a github repository:

```
-e git://github.com/dfrankow/django-editorjs-fields.git#egg=django-editorjs-fields
```

Running `pip-compile req.in` gives a `req.txt` with

```
-e git+git://github.com/dfrankow/django-editorjs-fields.git#egg=django-editorjs-fields
```

Using `pip` to install (`pip install -r req.txt`) gives this error:

```
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: .../.venv/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'.../.venv/src/django-editorjs-fields/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'.../.venv/src/django-editorjs-fields/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps
         cwd: .../.venv/src/django-editorjs-fields/
    Complete output (3 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

I have setuptools (and in fact all the other libraries) installed.  See, no errors:

```
$ .venv/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize;'
$
```

If I install directly (without the `-e`) it works:

```
$ pip install git+git://github.com/dfrankow/django-editorjs-fields.git#egg=django-editorjs-fields
... (works)
```

But when I take the `-e` out of `req.in`, `pip-compile` complains:

```
$ pip-compile req.in
...
pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Invalid requirement: 'git://github.com/dfrankow/django-editorjs-fields.git#egg=django-editorjs-fields' (from line 1 of req.in)
Hint: It looks like a path. File 'git://github.com/dfrankow/django-editorjs-fields.git#egg=django-editorjs-fields' does not exist.
```

What the heck, I'm trapped.

How do I put a github repo into req.in, compile it with pip-compile into req.txt, and pip install req.txt without errors?

I need it to work automatically because we have a toolchain that depends on it (github workflows, dependabot, ..).

I'm using python 3.9.1_2, pip 21.1.2, pip-tools 6.2.0 on OS X.  Also happened with pip-tools 6.0.1 (not surprising).

Comment: FYI I ended up editing requirements.txt by hand every time.

Comment: try with `git+https://github.com/dfrankow/django-editorjs-fields.git#egg=django-editorjs-fields`.This should work, but it won't pin any dependencies of the djang-editorjs-fields package, which is odd...

Answer (score 1):

Use the following format for git requirements:

```
$ cat requirements.in
django-editorjs-fields @ git+https://github.com/dfrankow/django-editorjs-fields
```

Result:

```
$ pip-compile
#
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile with Python 3.11
# by the following command:
#
#    pip-compile
#
django-editorjs-fields @ git+https://github.com/dfrankow/django-editorjs-fields.git
    # via -r requirements.in
```